# How do i put a script in Customtkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, encoding, decoding

im new to coding and i want to code a caeser encoder. I have the script for encoding ready, but i want to put it in a customtkinter window where i can write in the encoder number and the text and he gives me the encoded text, how do i start, i have created a window but i dont know what to do know...

So know i have to put this script for the encoder in the window.

Window creater

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("780x400")
app.title("CustomTkinter simple_example.py")




app.mainloop()
```

Encoder

```
print("--CEASAR GELUMP--")
while True:
    offset = input("GEBEN SIE DIE VERSCHIEBUNG AN: ")
    if offset == "exit":
        break
    else:
        offset = int(offset)
    text = input("GEBEN SIE DEN  ZU VERSCHLÜSSELNDEN TEXT EIN:\n")
    output = ""
    for i in text:
        output+=chr(ord(i)+offset)
    print(output)
print("ENDE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("780x400")
app.title("CustomTkinter Caesar Encoder")

def caesar_encode(offset, text):
    output = ""
    for i in text:
        output += chr(ord(i) + offset)
    return output

def on_encode():
    offset = int(offset_entry.get())
    text = text_entry.get()
    encoded_text = caesar_encode(offset, text)
    output_label.config(text=encoded_text)

offset_label = tk.Label(app, text="GEBEN SIE DIE VERSCHIEBUNG AN:")
offset_label.pack()

offset_entry = tk.Entry(app)
offset_entry.pack()

text_label = tk.Label(app, text="GEBEN SIE DEN ZU VERSCHLÜSSELNDEN TEXT EIN:")
text_label.pack()

text_entry = tk.Entry(app)
text_entry.pack()

encode_button = tk.Button(app, text="Encode", command=on_encode)
encode_button.pack()

output_label = tk.Label(app)
output_label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: C:\Users\Planky\Desktop\caeser\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Planky\Desktop\caeser\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Planky\Desktop\caeser\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    offset_label = customtkinter.Label(app, text="GEBEN SIE DIE VERSCHIEBUNG AN:")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'Label'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I have changed the code, it should work now